# Curl: Send request just like a browser

Tags: linux, google-chrome, http, curl

Searching theatres on Google returns future events in an instant panel. See the Showtimes panel below for example:
[image]

I am trying to pull Google instance information using `curl`. However, it seems Google somehow figures that this is a bot not a real browser request. Response received by curl has the instant panel excluded. Here is the curl call I use:

```
    curl -H "DNT: 1" -H "UPGRADE-INSECURE-REQUESTS: 1" \
-H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8" \
-H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8" \
-H "REFERER: https://www.google.com/" \
-H "X-ACCEL-INTERNAL: /internal-nginx-static-location" \
-H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36" \
-v "https://www.google.com/search?q=rio+theatre&oq=rio+theatre&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2382j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8"
```

How can I modify curl to retrieve the same information as the browser does?

Comment: instead of pretending that you are chrome can't you try pretending that you are IE or another browser?

Comment: Can you try generating a HAR file using chrome and registering the HTTP traffic that is flowing? Then you can use https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/har_analyzer/ to analyze the first HTTP GET and use the same headers + cookie

Comment: My guess is that this is some information from an Ajax request, and curl does not perform any Javascript. You will need to get this information using e.g. `selenium`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.